# Degraded performance when upgrading from 10.04 to 12.04 and 14.04

Tags: upgrade, performance

Our issue is the difference in performance observed when upgrading from Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04 and 14.04.

We've done some simple reproducible tests that show that even Vanilla Ubuntu 10.04 instances perform better when handling large traffics load when compared to Vanilla Ubuntu 14.04 instances.

The results of our tests are tabulated here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xNy4x31smP1LXEdbhygDDyr6CL7GfzZbqkicK2b6e0w

For many of our instances in AWS, we have decided to continue using 10.04 simply because of the extensive performance degradation we see on ubuntu 14.04.

We've also posted this question here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/296388 in greater detail and have explained how to recreate the difference in performance we observed.

We’ve been unable to identify the source of the performance discrepancy, if anyone has any insights or info we would really appreciate it.

EDIT: I may not have been clear in explaining the issue. By upgrading, I mean doing a clean install of the new Ubuntu version.

Second EDIT: We've separated the performance issue from our applications. If you look at our tabulated benchmark results [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xNy4x31smP1LXEdbhygDDyr6CL7GfzZbqkicK2b6e0w), it shows that even Vanilla instances that have clean installs of Trusty and Lucid show wide fluctuations in max load average observed during the Apache Test, which performs 1,000,000 requests with 100 requests being carried out concurrently.

Braiam, I do like your idea of doing an incremental update and seeing exactly where the issue surfaces. I'll be giving that a try, thanks!

Third Edit:
So I did some more testing across recent Ubuntu Server Versions and I've graphed the data below. The Apache Test I am referring to in the graph is from https://openbenchmarking.org/test/pts/apache
[image: Performance Results Across Ubuntu Versions]

Comment: Are you necessarily *upgrading* from one to the next, or doing fresh installs of each successive version? Just wondering; I'm interesting in looking into that. I run 12.04, 14.04, and 16.04, and 12.xx seems to work the best for me, and that's on older machines.

Comment: It can be anything, really. From your applications not being optimized to the inherent features that make the system doing the same operations just slower. I would recommend doing incremental test on all non-LTS releases to figure out where exactly is the discrepancy, as no one can figure out which out of the 200 packages with accumulative changes for 2 years is the culprit.

Comment: I wonder if part of the problem might be that the fixes for issues with reported load averages being incorrect (way way too low) might never have been backported to 10.04. see commit c308b56b5398779cd3da0f62ab26b0453494c3d4 from March 2012. There are other related commits, but that was the main one.

Comment: It's not just a superficial issue with regards to reporting. We've seen slower response times from servers running Ubuntu 14.04 compared to servers running Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: This is starting to look like an issue report… still off topic. AU is not the right platform to resolve non-trivial technical issues that the developers of the software stack in question couldn't resolve themselves so far.